# Hibernate Must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one, composite-key

I am new to Hibernate annotation mapping , i am trying to do the following mapping which seems to be simple. One Application --> Can Have Multiple MissingFacebookAd
The catch is that MissingFacebookAd have Embeddable composite key which should be some how to be reference , below my code Please Advice : 
**Application.java**

```
Entity
@Cache(region = "application", usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name= "application")
public class Application implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private Advertiser advertiser;
    private String name;
    private Set<MissingFacebookAd> missingFacebookAd;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public Set<MissingFacebookAd> getMissingFacebookAdSet() {
        return missingFacebookAd;
    }


    public void setMissingFacebookAd(Set<MissingFacebookAd> missingFacebookAd) {
        this.missingFacebookAd = missingFacebookAd;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="advertiser_id")
    public Advertiser getAdvertiser() {
        return advertiser;
    }

    public void setAdvertiser(Advertiser advertiser) {
        this.advertiser = advertiser;
    }

    @Column(name ="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**MissingFacebookAd.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "missing_fb_ad")
public class MissingFacebookAd implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId id;

    public MissingFacebookAd(Application application, long adgroupIdInTarget) {
        ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId id = new ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId(application, adgroupIdInTarget);
        this.id = id;
    }

    private MissingFacebookAd() {
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        MissingFacebookAd that = (MissingFacebookAd) o;

        if (!id.equals(that.id)) return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

The **ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId.java** (Key Class)

```
@Embeddable
public class ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Application application;
    private long adgroupId;

    public ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId(Application application, long adgroupId) {
        this.application = application;
        this.adgroupId = adgroupId;
    }

    private ApplicationAndFbAdgroupId() {
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="application_id")
    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }
    @Column(name="adgroup_id")
    public long getAdgroupId() {
        return adgroupId;
    }

    public void setAdgroupId(long adgroupId) {
        this.adgroupId = adgroupId;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your OneToMany is not mapped by "id". It's mapped by "id.application": that's where the corresponfin ManyToOne is defined. That said, I strongly advise to use a purely technical, autogenerated primary key for your enties, and to avoid composite ids.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ,  when changed to id.application it throws an exception that it could not find setter for missingFacebookAdSet in Application class , even thought there is a setter , below exception message :
Could not find a setter for property missingFacebookAdSet in class .....persistant.model.Application

Comment: There is a setter, but it's named setMissingFacebookAd, whereas the getter is named getMissingFacebookAdSet(). So they don't match. So the error message is absolutely right.